# Mahjong Probability Graph Question

Tags: probability, mahjong

[image]

Picture from [pierebean's](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/908/in-mahjong-what-is-the-chance-to-get-a-hand-that-allows-a-player-to-finish-on/51133#51133) post in [In Mahjong , what is the chance to get a hand that allows a player to finish on their first turn?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/908/in-mahjong-what-is-the-chance-to-get-a-hand-that-allows-a-player-to-finish-on)

I was wondering what the graph on the right meant? How does the number of mahjong hands & the mean number of draws correlate to the graphs on the left and why would they form an exponential-shaped graph?

And how does the exponential shaped graph relate to the poisson distribution at all?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about board games, it's about understanding how to read the graph. As such it more properly belongs on either the maths or stats SE.